# Добавить "+/-" до и после input

Tags: html, jquery, css, drupal

Приветствую. Есть ли какая то возможность (через jQuery или CSS) добавить знаки + после инпута и знак -  перед ним? При этом чтоб они располагались не за пределами label?
Пробовал через псевдоэлементы before и after, но их насколько я знаю только к div можно применить, к самому input никак.
К формированию самой формы доступа нет, так как она формируется через модуль Drupal 7.
Необходимо мне все это для того чтоб потом прописать по нажатию на эти элементы изменение значения самого инпута.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: для начала посмотрите `<input type="number">` возможно этого будет достаточно.

Comment: что означает : "При этом чтоб они располагались не за пределами label"?

Comment: На before и after не повесить клик

Comment: А как в данном случае можно поступить? Чтоб потом можно было повесить событие клика?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение, сделал так:

```
$('.form-number').before('-');
```